# How to display a video player in a loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I am using a JW video player and the way it is implemented for a single video is as below

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "<?php echo $dbVideoFile; ?>"
});

</script>

</div>
```

No what I want to do is that I want to do is loop through each existing video and to display a jw video player for each video. Only problem is that it is not quite working, it is only display the jsplayer for one video, the other videos do not show anything but blank. What am I doing wrong below:

```
    <p>
<?php foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">


jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>"
});

</script>

</div>
<?php } ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id tag should be unic so JWPlayer is confused when calling #myElement

Try incrementing a value and dynamically rename "myElement-" + i

I didn't get to test but that shoudl work:

```
  <p>
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>
<div id="myElement-<?php echo $i; ?>">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">


jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>"
});

<?php $i++; ?>
</script>

</div>
<?php } ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show me how to write the loop to increment, I have only used while and foreach loops, I think your stating for loop but need to learn this so if I see sample then I can refer to this as future use

Comment: Your very close. I will create a seperate question and mark this as best answer but what is happening is lets say I have 2 questions which I access through a loop and question 1 has two videos and question 2 has a video, it displays the 2 videos for question 1 but for question 2 it does not display a video, it just displays `Loading video player ... `. Can I send you link to seperate queston in comment below for you to see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764584/it-is-not-displaying-video-players-for-all-existing-videos - link to separate question

Comment: you don't need a new question as it is the same problem - now you end up having twice myElement-0, etc since you're running the loop twice. Just use a different id name for the second loop