# It is not displaying video players for all existing videos

Tags: php, javascript, jwplayer

What is happening is lets say I have 2 questions which I access through a loop and question 1 has two videos and question 2 has a video, it displays the 2 videos for question 1 but for question 2 it does not display a video, it just displays `Loading video player ...`. How can I get the video to be displayed for question 2 as well as question one?

Below is code:

```
<?php

foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {


                //start:procedure video
        $vid_result = '';
        if(empty($arrVideoFile[$key])){
          $vid_result = '&nbsp;';
        }else{

            ?>

  <p>
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>
<div id="myElement-<?php echo $i; ?>">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">


jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>"
});

<?php $i++; ?>
</script>

</div>
<?php } ?>
</p>

<?php           
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe try cleaning up the code?

Comment: your have duplicate ids for `myElement-n` after the first iteration of `$arrQuestionId` as `$i` will be reset, add `$key` to `myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>`

Comment: Isn't it remarkable how two people can say the same thing, basically, and yet one person is precise and helpful while the other is a snarky troll?  I think so!